# How do i display multiple separate query results into options in a single drop down box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

Please refer to the quick and dirty jfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Dano007/b11xarpp/5/

The bounty is to get the below answer working with the an updated jfiddle. Bascially having the drop down menu display the two options for the functions. The when one of those of options is clicked the results are returned on the page.

I think the answer below will help with how to approach this, hoever I've hot a brick wall with my attempts.

If you click the buttons, this is the end results I'd like to duplicate when using the filter.

**Code**

```
</head>

<body>

    <!--Drop down filter box that should show each option returned from functions below-->

    <form>
        <select name="huge" class="btn-group select select-block mbl select-multiple" id="select#FriendsConnected">
            <option value="0">Filter Friends/Requests</option>
        </select>

        <button id="FriendsConnected" type="button" class="button button-magenta">Connected Friends</button>
        <button id="FriendsPending" type="button" class="button button-orange">Friend Requests</button>
    </form>

    <!--Displays content/images on page after filter-->
    <div id="container">
        <div id="userimgs" class="responsive-image"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="containerFriendsPending"></div>
    <div id="containerFriendsConnected"></div>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="badgeimgs"></div>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        Parse.initialize("79tphN5KrDXdjJnAmehgBHgOjgE2dLGTvEPR9pEJ", "9lblofQNZlypAtveU4i4IzEpaOqtBgMcmuU1AE6Y");

    Parse.User.logIn("dave", "delvedia", {
        success: function(user) {
            console.log("Logged in!");
        }
    });


         /////////Filter One///////////////////
        function FriendsPending() {

            $('#containerFriends').empty();
            $('#containerFriendsRejected').empty();
            $('#containerFriendsRequestSent').empty();
            $('#containerFriendsConnected').empty();


            var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
            var FriendRequest = Parse.Object.extend("FriendRequest");

            var query = new Parse.Query(FriendRequest);
            query.include('toUser');
            query.include('SentTo');
            query.include("myBadge");
            query.equalTo("fromUser", currentUser);
            query.equalTo("status", "Pending");

            query.find({
                success: function(results) {
                    var friends = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                        friends.push({
                            imageURL: results[i].get('toUser').get('pic'),
                            friendRequestId: results[i].id,
                            username: results[i].get('toUser').get('username'),
                            userId: results[i].get('toUser').id


                        });


                    }
                    var select = document.getElementById("FriendsPending");
                    $.each(friends, function(i, v) {
                        var opt = v.username;
                        var el = document.createElement("option");
                        el.textContent = opt;
                        el.value = opt;
                        select.appendChild(el);
                    })

                    _.each(friends, function(item) {
                        var wrapper = $('<div class="wrapper"' + ' data-friend-request-id="' + item.friendRequestId + '"' + ' data-to-user-id="' + item.userId + '"></div>');
                        wrapper.append('<img class="images responsive-image BadgeImgOutline" src="' + item.imageURL + '" />');
                        wrapper.append('<div>' + item.username + '</div>');
                        wrapper.append('<div type="button" class="button button-blue">' + 'Accept Friend' + '</div>');
                        wrapper.append('<div type="button" class="button button-yellow">' + 'Decline' + '</div>');
                        $('#containerFriendsPending').append(wrapper);
                    });

                },
                error: function(error) {
                    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                }
            });

        }

         /////////Filter Two///////////////////
        function FriendsConnected() {
            $('#containerFriendsRejected').empty();
            $('#containerFriendsPending').empty();
            $('#containerFriendsRequestSent').empty();
            var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
            var FriendRequest = Parse.Object.extend("FriendRequest");

            var query = new Parse.Query(FriendRequest);
            query.include('toUser');
            query.include('SentTo');
            query.include("myBadge");
            query.equalTo("fromUser", currentUser);
            query.equalTo("status", "Connected");

            query.find({
                success: function(results) {
                    var friends = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                        friends.push({
                            imageURL: results[i].get('toUser').get('pic'),
                            friendRequestId: results[i].id,
                            username: results[i].get('toUser').get('username'),
                            userId: results[i].get('toUser').id


                        });


                    }
                    var select = document.getElementById("FriendsConnected");
                    $.each(friends, function(i, v) {
                        var opt = v.username;
                        var el = document.createElement("option");
                        el.textContent = opt;
                        el.value = opt;
                        select.appendChild(el);
                    })


                    _.each(friends, function(item) {
                        var wrapper = $('<div class="wrapper"' + ' data-friend-request-id="' + item.friendRequestId + '"' + ' data-to-user-id="' + item.userId + '"></div>');
                        wrapper.append('<img class="images responsive-image BadgeImgOutline" src="' + item.imageURL + '" />');
                        wrapper.append('<div>' + item.username + '</div>');
                        $('#containerFriendsConnected').append(wrapper);
                    });

                },
                error: function(error) {
                    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                }
            });
        }

         //////////////////////////Takes results from functions and adds them to div to show///////////////////////////////

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#FriendsPending').click(function(e) {
                FriendsPending();
            });


            $('#FriendsConnected').click(function(e) {
                FriendsConnected();
            });


        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full details of how this can be answered can be found here.

[How to bind multiple function results as options to select in a form select pop down box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25555368/how-to-bind-multiple-function-results-as-options-to-select-in-a-form-select-pop/25555605#25555605)

The code is as follows

HTML

```
<!--Drop down filter box that should show each option returned from functions below-->

    <form>
        <select name="huge" class="btn-group select select-block mbl select-multiple" id="s_Friends">
            <option value="0">Filter Friends/Requests</option>
            <option value="f_connected">Connected Friends</option>
            <option value="f_requests">Friend Requests</option>
        </select>
    </form>

    <!--Displays content/images on page after filter-->
    <div id="container">
        <div id="userimgs" class="responsive-image"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="containerFriendsPending"></div>
    <div id="containerFriendsConnected"></div>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="badgeimgs"></div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
Parse.initialize("ccccc", "xxxxx");

    Parse.User.logIn("dave", "delvedia", {
        success: function(user) {
            console.log("Logged in!");
        }
    });


         /////////Filter One///////////////////
        function FriendsPending() {

            $('#containerFriends').empty();
            $('#containerFriendsRejected').empty();
            $('#containerFriendsRequestSent').empty();
            $('#containerFriendsConnected').empty();


            var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
            var FriendRequest = Parse.Object.extend("FriendRequest");

            var query = new Parse.Query(FriendRequest);
            query.include('toUser');
            query.include('SentTo');
            query.include("myBadge");
            query.equalTo("fromUser", currentUser);
            query.equalTo("status", "Pending");

            query.find({
                success: function(results) {
                    var friends = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                        friends.push({
                            imageURL: results[i].get('toUser').get('pic'),
                            friendRequestId: results[i].id,
                            username: results[i].get('toUser').get('username'),
                            userId: results[i].get('toUser').id


                        });


                    }

                    _.each(friends, function(item) {
                        var wrapper = $('<div class="wrapper"' + ' data-friend-request-id="' + item.friendRequestId + '"' + ' data-to-user-id="' + item.userId + '"></div>');
                        wrapper.append('<img class="images responsive-image BadgeImgOutline" src="' + item.imageURL + '" />');
                        wrapper.append('<div>' + item.username + '</div>');
                        wrapper.append('<div type="button" class="button button-blue">' + 'Accept Friend' + '</div>');
                        wrapper.append('<div type="button" class="button button-yellow">' + 'Decline' + '</div>');
                        $('#containerFriendsPending').append(wrapper);
                    });

                },
                error: function(error) {
                    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                }
            });

        }

         /////////Filter Two///////////////////
        function FriendsConnected() {
            $('#containerFriendsRejected').empty();
            $('#containerFriendsPending').empty();
            $('#containerFriendsRequestSent').empty();
            var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
            var FriendRequest = Parse.Object.extend("FriendRequest");

            var query = new Parse.Query(FriendRequest);
            query.include('toUser');
            query.include('SentTo');
            query.include("myBadge");
            query.equalTo("fromUser", currentUser);
            query.equalTo("status", "Connected");

            query.find({
                success: function(results) {
                    var friends = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                        friends.push({
                            imageURL: results[i].get('toUser').get('pic'),
                            friendRequestId: results[i].id,
                            username: results[i].get('toUser').get('username'),
                            userId: results[i].get('toUser').id


                        });


                    }

                    _.each(friends, function(item) {
                        var wrapper = $('<div class="wrapper"' + ' data-friend-request-id="' + item.friendRequestId + '"' + ' data-to-user-id="' + item.userId + '"></div>');
                        wrapper.append('<img class="images responsive-image BadgeImgOutline" src="' + item.imageURL + '" />');
                        wrapper.append('<div>' + item.username + '</div>');
                        $('#containerFriendsConnected').append(wrapper);
                    });

                },
                error: function(error) {
                    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                }
            });
        }

         //////////////////////////Takes results from functions and adds them to div to show///////////////////////////////

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('select#s_Friends').change(function(){

            var selection = $(this).val();

            if(selection=='f_connected')
            FriendsConnected();

            else if(selection=='f_requests')
            FriendsPending();

            });
```

Answer (score 2):

For beginners, you can use `.append()` or `appendTo()` function to add the `option` to your select box.

Since there are multiple sources, I would probably bind a class to it that tells me how to filter it.  I would create my propagation functions to add a new option and include its filter type/source as a class:

```
    function prop1(){
       $("<option/>")
         .val('The Value')
         .html('Display Text')
         .addClass('filter-prop1')
         .appendTo('select#FriendsConnected');
    }
```

Now I have my second function that does the same, except change the binded class name to `filter-prop2`:

```
    function prop2(){
       $("<option/>")
         .val('The Value')
         .html('Display Text')
         .addClass('filter-prop2')
         .appendTo('select#FriendsConnected');
    }
```

Now you can show/hide the options based on its type like this:

```
 $("select#FriendsConnected option.filter-prop2").hide();
 $("select#FriendsConnected option.filter-prop1").show();
```

This will hide all options from the 2nd propagation and show only the options from the first propagation, and so on, but is only an example.