# How to bind multiple function results as options to select in a form select pop down box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Dano007/b11xarpp/5/

To be clearer. In the drop down box, I'd like two options (text). when the user clicks one of these options the relevant function results are returned. Like see when clicking the buttons, which are for example only.

I've added the drop down box, but cannot see how to bind the results from the two queries to it.

Could I use something like ?

```
$("select#FriendsConnected option.filter-prop2").show();
$("select#FriendsConnected option.filter-prop1").show();
```

Feel like I've hot a brick wall with this and ideally would like some help with the fiddle to move past it.

Comment: You want to make a button in every item of the drop down menu?

Comment: @GustavoPinent sorry, to be clearer. In the drop down box, I'd liek two options (text). when the user clicks one of these options the relevant function results are returned. Like see when clicking the buttons, which are for example only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML, change select id to a valid css id, something like: `s_FriendsConnected`

```
<select name="huge" class="btn-group select select-block mbl select-multiple" id="s_FriendsConnected">
```

In your Javascript, change the select = getElementByID(FriendsConnected)'s ID to your new select id: `s_FriendsConnected`

```
var select = document.getElementById("s_FriendsConnected");
```

This solves it on my local machine... will update with the jsfiddle in a while..

EDIT:

Here's the jsfiddle. : http://jsfiddle.net/b11xarpp/7/

UPDATE:::

As per your requirement, in this new jsfiddle, I've removed the buttons and placed option tags with values in the html.
In Javascript, I've removed the var `select = document.getelementbyid()` function. 
Also, I've replaced your `click` functions for the buttons with `on Change` event to the `select` menu:

```
$('select#s_Friends').change(function(){

            var selection = $(this).val();

            if(selection=='f_connected')
            FriendsConnected();

            else if(selection=='f_requests')
            FriendsPending();

            });
```

That's mostly all. Here's the updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b11xarpp/8/

Comment: thanks, think there is still some confusion. The purpose of the select box is so the user can select an option for "FriendsConnected" or "FriendsPending" when they click on that it returns the results to the page. The buttons are only there to illustrate what should happen after the user clicks an option in the select box. Does that help?

Comment: So what are you trying to do? Your content is being displayed via the buttons, and if you need to bind these buttons behaviors to the select menu options instead, you should use `(select).on('change', function() {}` and add something similar to `this.hyperlink.click` enabling loading of your content on change of the select menu option. I cannot create a jsfiddle right now, but that's mostly what I think will be how the code could be...

Comment: You summary seems inline with what I'm trying to do, basically the select menu will replace the buttons. If you could update your answer I'm happy to accept this!